Solve the recurrence, $C_N = C_{N/2} + N^2$, for $N \ge 2 $ with $C_1 = 0 $ when N is a power of 2.
I am currently studying Algorithms in C from Robert Sedgewick's book and there are some recurrence mathematical problems in Chapter 2 that I am having difficulty with.
$C_N = C_{N/2} + N^2$ for $N = 2^n$
$C_{2^n} = C_{2^{n-1}} + 2^{2n}$
Expanding the equation I end up with :
$C_{2^n} = C_{2^{n-2}} + 2^{2(n-1)} + 2^{2n}$
$C_{2^n} = C_{2^{n-3}} + 2^{2(n-2)} + 2^{2(n-1)} + 2^{2n}$
$C_{2^n} = C_{2^{n-4}} + 2^{2(n-3)} + 2^{2(n-2)} + 2^{2(n-1)} + 2^{2n}$
eventually it will be:
$C_{2^n} = C_1 + 2^{2(n-n)} + 2^{2(n-(n-1))} + ... + 2^{2(n-3)} + 2^{2(n-2)} + 2^{2(n-1)} + 2^{2n}$
$C_{2^n} = 0 + 1 + 2^{2(1)} + ... + 2^{2(n-3)} + 2^{2(n-2)} + 2^{2(n-1)} + 2^{2n}$
Now should I take the first term as $2^{2n}$ in which case the geometric ratio with be $2^2$ (i.e. > 1 and the series will not converge) or should it be the other way around so that first term is $2^2$ in which sum of the series will be $\frac{2^2}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$ (16/3). So, $C_N = \frac{16}{3} + 1$?
Or have I solved the entire thing incorrectly?

I've done this in this way:
The recurrence given is:
$$C_N=C_{N/2}+N^2$$
We do the transformation: $N \rightarrow \dfrac{N}{2} $
This yields:
$$C_{N/2}=C_{N/4}+\left(\dfrac{N}{4}\right)^2$$
Substituting this in previous equation, yields:
$$C_N=C_{N/4}+\left(\dfrac{N}{2}\right)^2+N^2$$
We can repeat this exercise for total $(k)$ times, where $N=2^k$, until we get $C_1$, which is $0$.
We can write that in this way:
$$C_N=C_1+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left(\dfrac{N}{2^i}\right)^2 =N^2\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{1}{4^i} =N^2 \cdot \dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{4^{k}}}{1-\dfrac{1}{4}} $$
$$=N^2\cdot\dfrac{4^{k}-1}{3\cdot 4^k}\cdot4$$
Since $N^2=4^k$, we can rewrite that as:
$$N^2\cdot\dfrac{4(N^2-1)}{3N^2}$$
Thus,$$ \boxed {C_N=\dfrac{4}{3}\cdot \left(N^2-1\right)}.$$
Am I correct?
I think I am. Here's why:
For $N=2$, we have $C_2=2^2=4,$ which agrees with my formula as $\dfrac{4}{3}(2^2-1)=4.$
For $N=4$, we have $C_4=4^2+C_2=20$, which again agrees with my formula as $\dfrac{4}{3}(4^2-1)=20.$

This cleared it up. Thanks!

Hey, thanks! But the the solution you have given a green tick mark isn't correct, so I don't understand why you've approved that...I don't want to be mean to that person, I'm just saying/asking...since that person's answer is $\dfrac{4N^2-1}{3}$, which is wrong, but mine, which is, $\dfrac{4}{3}(N^2-1)$ is correct. You can plug in different values of $N$ and convince yourself which is correct.

Thanks so much! Can you please upvote my answer, so that my rank may get more and I can then gain more privileges ? (I don't want to force you, it's up to you, I'm just requesting...)

For this kind of question, it is often simpler to define an auxiliary sequence.
Here I would define the $u$ sequence by $u_n=C_{2^n} + 1$, to have $u_0=1$. We can control for the first terms of the sequence:
$$\begin{aligned}
C_1 &= 0 &u_0 = 1 = 2^{2\times 0}\\
C_2 &= 0 + 2^2 = 4 &u_1 = 1 + 4 = 2^{2\times 0} + 2^{2\times 1}\\
C_4 &= 4 + 4^2 = 20 &u_2 = 1 + 20 = 1+ 4 + 16 = 2^{2\times 0} + 2^{2\times 1}+2^{2\times 2}\\
\end{aligned}$$
We finally get:
$u_n = 2^{2\times 0} + 2^{2\times 1} + \dots + 2^{2n}$
With the remark: $\forall n\in \Bbb N, 2^{2n} = (2^2)^n$, we get (sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric sequence):
$$u_n = \sum_{i=0}^n{(2^2)^i}=\frac{(2^2)^{n+1}-1}{(2^2)-1}=\frac{2^{2n+2}-1}{3}$$
Going back to the original sequence we have for $N=2^n, n\in\Bbb N$
$$C_N=\frac{4N^2-1}3-1$$
because $2^{2n+2}= 2^2\times 2^{2n}= 2^2\times (2^n)^2= 4\times(2^n)^2$ and $C_{2^n} = u_n-1$
Finally:
$$C_N = \frac{4N^2-1}3-1= \frac{4N^2-1-3}3= \frac{4N^2-4}3=\frac 4 3(N^2-1)$$

Unfortunately your answer is not entirely correct. You can quickly check it yourself using the initial condition "$C_1=0$". Your solution yields $C_1=1$, but $1\ne0$. The problem is that you ignored the fact that there are multiple homogenous solutions (all constants).

@KevinDietrich: Oops... You are right, of course! I missed the $C_1=0$ condition that only appeared in the title. It should be correct now. And thank you for your remark...

There are indeed some errors. Whether the series converges or not doesn't matter, because you are not finding the infinite sum.
According to wiki

Plus, you are finding the closed form of $C_N$, and $N$ is finite, it is eqivalent to the first part of the statment in the above picture.

$$C_N=C_{2^n}=C_1+\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2(n-i)}$$
The series is a finite sum.
